# How to use alias in a loop?

Tags: maple

If I do this

```
restart;
L[1]:=x^2-2;
L[2]:=x^2-3;
alias(alpha=RootOf(L[1])):
evala(Factor(L[1],alpha));
alias(alpha=RootOf(L[2])):
evala(Factor(L[2],alpha));
```

then it factors nicely:

```
(x+alpha)*(x-alpha)
(x+alpha)*(x-alpha)
```

But if I do the same in a loop then `alias` is not working:

```
restart;
L[1]:=x^2-2:
L[2]:=x^2-3:
for i from 1 to 2 do
  alias(alpha=RootOf(L[i])):
  print(evala(Factor(L[i],alpha)));
end do:
```

The result:

```
x^2-2
x^2-3
```

Is there a way to use `alias` in a loop properly?